# Why does Facetime echo and Zoom does not?

Tags: facetime, video-conference, zoom.app

Huge echo with my living room setup when using Facetime on a Mac Mini with external camera (nice Logitech). Zero echo using Zoom. Or really, anything else. Even Skype seems fine.

The echo is heard by the party being called, but not on our end. The microphone is on the logitech camera (C910, and BRIO, both attempted), the speaker is out of the TV. I have attempted to move both, turn down the TV volume, change positioning in the room, etc...

Of course, it is convenient to use Facetime, but actually my mother and father are using this as the seed of a 'let's buy Samsung phones' plan. They hear good things. They switch, I'll likely need to switch.

I'll not be buying a Mac all-in-one to fix this.

Any help? I'd really prefer not to spent winter break learning Android.

Comment: Who hears the echo - you or them?

Comment: Is the microphone on the Logitech camera?

Comment: Check to see if [Background Noise Suppression](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360046244692) has been enabled in Zoom.

Comment: They hear the echo, microphone on-camera, zoom has no issue with echo, only Facetime.

Comment: I could just use Zoom, but that plays into a larger 'ditch apple' push in my family. I like Apple things.

Comment: I think the unfortunate answer here is that Skype and Zoom have features built-in to reduce echo, and FaceTime does not. I don't think you can do much except start using Zoom and if they decide to switch, well, you can still use Zoom if you want to talk to them.

Comment: This is also my hunch, although I do not want it to be true. Rough that Apple has not innovated here, nor even kept pace...  It plays into a larger narrative I hear a lot from mac users in transition: eventually the world moved forward and they had to hop platforms to keep up...

Answer (score 0):

Don't go Android, it's not an OS problem. I've had the same problem. Big (32-inch) monitor with an excellent BRIO Logitech 4K webcam. Does not matter the conferencing app, but if I use the BRIO mic, the echo on the other end is horrible (in most cases, horribly funny). So I just use the Mac (in my case MacBook Pro)'s mic.  Since you I suggest you just get an external Mic - it is best if you can test it before, or buy and return if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Long since went to Android. Interestingly Facetime on Android (Pixel 7) displays no echo, while an iPhone 14 does. Android is objectively vastly better, by any measure I can think of except interoperability with Macs. As a result I now have a windows machine. Likewise vastly better.  It's been a very pleasant transition. I owe it all to this post.